# How to read from a text file in python line by line

Tags: python, file

I have a text file that consists of points of 4 dimensions each point.

The file is like this:

```
4.8 3.4 1.6 0.2 
4.8 3.0 1.4 0.1 
4.3 3.0 1.1 0.1 
5.8 4.0 1.2 0.2 
5.7 4.4 1.5 0.4 
5.4 3.9 1.3 0.4 
5.1 3.5 1.4 0.3
```

I want to read the file and store each line of the file as a seperate list.For instance `point1=[4,8 3,4 1,6 0,2].`

What I have done so far is :

```
f= open('points.txt', 'r')            
    data = f.readlines()

    for line in data:
        pList= line.rstrip()
        print (pList)
```

I get a list of all the points.

Comment: You may use `pList.split()`.

Comment: Which will give you a list of strings, you can then use `float` to convert them to numbers. I'd suggest finding and following a basic tutorial.

Comment: Just `for line in f:` is all you need.

Comment: Correct your indentation  and this will already create a list of lines `data = f.readlines()`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You might find Python's [CSV](https://docs.python.org/2/library/csv.html#module-csv) module useful for this:

```
import csv

with open('points.txt', 'r') as f_input:
    points = list(csv.reader(f_input, delimiter='\t'))

# To convert to floats
points = [map(float, x) for x in points]

print points
```

This would display the following:

```
[[4.8, 3.4, 1.6, 0.2], [4.8, 3.0, 1.4, 0.1], [4.3, 3.0, 1.1, 0.1], [5.8, 4.0, 1.2, 0.2], [5.7, 4.4, 1.5, 0.4], [5.4, 3.9, 1.3, 0.4], [5.1, 3.5, 1.4, 0.3]]
```

Comment: I actually get this: [['5.1\t3.5\t1.4\t0.2\t'], ['4.9\t3.0\t1.4\t0.2\t'], ['4.7\t3.2\t1.3\t0.2\t'], ['4.6\t3.1\t1.5\t0.2\t']

Comment: Your file is tab delimited, simply change the delimiter to `delimiter='\t'` and it should work.

Comment: thank you..if I want to convert the items of the lists into floats? I do  map(float, points) but it doesn't work

Comment: Almost, you just need to do that for each sub-list as follows: `points = [map(float, x) for x in points]`

Answer (score 0):

Try with :

```
f= open('points.txt', 'r')            
data = f.readlines()

for line in data:

    points = line.split()   
    print points
```